# Substrate Playground - Share workspace

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

I developed a [custom pallet](https://github.com/Apolixit/pallet_money_pot/blob/master/pallets/money-pot/src/lib.rs) and I would like to allow to try it easily for others developers.

Is it possible for me to share a [Substrate Playground](https://playground.substrate.dev) workspace and make it public?
I found I can save a workspace but it's only a link to my Github account.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Well done!

Follow [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/publish-custom-pallets/) to make it public for other developers publishing the pallet on [crates.io](https://crates.io/), the Rust community’s crate registry or on GitHub (You already did it).

It would be great to have it on the [Substrate Marketplace](https://marketplace.substrate.io/) too, check this [blog](https://www.parity.io/blog/introducing-substrate-marketplace-your-one-stop-resource-for-substrate-pallets) about how to feature on Substrate Marketplace.

Also I would recommend to document the pallet README, it makes it easy to know what is about and have a high-level understanding about it.

You can take the [Balances pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/balances) from Substrate FRAME as an example, in my opinion that README is a really great documentation of the pallet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I want to add some others functionnalities and add some tests and I will publish it on Substrate Marketplace :)
Thanks for the documentation, I'm going to read this !