# Contribute a pallet I've written to Polkadot Relay Chain

Tags: polkadot, pallet, substrate-node

is there a submission procedure for contributing a pallet I've written to Polkadot, for the relay chain?
I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

That's the [Polkadot repository](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk) where you can see the relay chain code. The code is open source and anyone can contribute, read carefully the [Contribution guide](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/docs/CONTRIBUTING.md).
For change to the technical implementation of the Polkadot network the process is first open Requests for Comment (RFC) in the [RFC repository](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/RFCs), read carefully the README there and specially how the [Process](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/RFCs#process) to submit a RFC works.

I suggest you to share your pallet with the community as it can be implemented in other chains, to do that check this previous StackExchange question: [Substrate Playground - Share workspace](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5517/substrate-playground-share-workspace/5519#5519) where I explained how to share your pallet in the [Substrate Marketplace](https://marketplace.substrate.io/).